# Data Migration Exception : Undefined offset: 1

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am trying to migrate data from Magento version `1.9.2.2 to 2.0.0 CE`

I was able to run `./magento migrate:settings` (mode) , but when I execute data mode, there was an error

```
[2016-02-16 05:45:23][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]:
 started

[2016-02-16 05:45:23][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer A
ttributes Step]: started

[2016-02-16 05:45:23][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]:
 started

[2016-02-16 05:45:31][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrit
e Step]: started

[2016-02-16 05:45:31][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]:
 started

[2016-02-16 05:45:31][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings St
ep]: started

[2016-02-16 05:45:31][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Configurab
lePrices step]: started

[2016-02-16 05:45:31][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids
 Step]: started

[2016-02-16 05:45:31][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price
 Step]: started

[2016-02-16 05:45:31][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncre
ment Step]: started

[2016-02-16 05:45:31][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: sta
rted

[2016-02-16 05:45:50][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]:
started

 [ErrorException]
 Undefined offset: 1
```

Noticed eav_attribute_set table in both Mage1 and Mage2 tables

[image]

[image]

What steps I have missed for migrating data ?

Comment: have you checked for migration log file inside var/log?

Comment: my var/log does not contain migration.log. But this file is in var/ which does not contain any recent logs